# Pandas dataframe groupby with aggregation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, group-by

I have a Pandas dataframe with thousands of rows, and these cols:

```
Name    Job   Department   Salary    Date
```

I want to return a new df with two cols:

```
Unique_Job     Avg_Salary
```

The code I use to accomplish this:

```
jobs = df.groupby(['Job'])
dict = {}
for a,b in jobs:
    dict.update({a: b['Salary'].mean()})
dfJobs = pd.DataFrame(dict.items(), columns=['Unique_Job', 'Avg Salary'])
```

However, I know there must be a better way.  Ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you just after `jobs['Salary'].mean()` as you're grouping already on jobs so I don't understand the need to iterate over the jobs again?

Comment: i think EdChum hit it on the nose. mean() will aggregate the data for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have the means, I guess you struggle with making the new dataframe from the series, you get as the output. You can use `Series.to_frame()` and `DataFrame.reset_index()` methods to make the dataframe with two columns and then you only rename the columns. Like this:

```
jobs = df.groupby('Job')['Salary'].mean()
jobs = jobs.to_frame().reset_index()
jobs.columns = ['Unique_Job', 'Avg_Salary']
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  use the `aggregate` method of the `groupby` object.

```
jobs = df.groupby('Job').aggregate({'Salary': 'mean'})
```

There's even the mean method as shortcut:

```
jobs = df.groupby('Job')['Salary'].mean()
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html 
for more info and lots of examples